# How to find the first character that repeats in a string?

Tags: python, string, list

For example, if the string is `pyeneapple` then the answer should be `p` since `p` is the first element that is present again in the string (and not `e`).

Can someone help with the Python code for this?

Here is my attempt:

```py
thestring = "pyeneapple"
list_a = []
list_b = []


for i in thestring:

    if i in list_a:
        list_b.append(i)
    else:
        list_a.append(i)

print(list_b[0])
```

The problem is that this code prints `e` as the answer instead of `p`.

Comment: The second `e` comes before the second `p`.

Comment: As @DevangSanghani pointed out, your approach finds the first "repeated" char. What you're trying to find is the first char that repeats

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I don't see how you can make a distinction between those two. The first character which repeats is the first repeated character.

Comment: My suspicion is that the test case is wrong, and you wanted to test "pyneapple" where indeed `p` is the first repeated character. Voting to close as typo / unreproducible.

Comment: @tripleee in "peep", "p" is the first character that will later repeat. The second "e" is the first character that repeats first

Comment: @tripleee list all characters that repeat -> ["p", "e"]. Which is the first one? It will be "p", not "e". Original char indexes matter, not the "repeated" ones

Answer (score 1):

You can replace comparing characters from string and then compare it to the string.

```
s = "pyeneapple"
a = []
 
for i in s:
    if i in s.replace(i, "", 1):
    a.append(i)

print(a[0])

Output: p
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a character counter to make it easier to implement and improve readability.

```py
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(s)
for i in s:
    if counts[i]>1:
        print(i)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function `enumerate()`:

```
for i, c in enumerate(thestring):
    if thestring[:i+1].count(c) > 1:
        print(c)
        break
```

Comment: Still prints `e`, how does it help OP?

Answer (score 0):

As there is a split point of view in the comment, I'm writing about the code giving the first element that repeats itself again in the behind strings.

```
thestring = "supercalifragi"
for i in range(len(thestring)):
    if thestring[i] in thestring[i+1:]:
        element = thestring[i]
        break
        

element
Out[10]: 'r'
```

Answer (score 0):

i would try with the buid-in count function for the *list-type* like this :

```
t = "pyeneapple"

for i in list(t):
    if t.count(i)>0:
        print(i)
        break

>>> p
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the first location using re.search where the string matches 2 of the same characters using a capture group and a backreference

```
import re

m = re.search(r"(.)\1", "pyeneapple")
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
p
```